# What is the exmon equivalent in Exchange 2010? (to get detailed per user information)

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2003, log-files, exchange, statistics

Exmon was an Exchange 2003 utility that exposed the quantity of RPC calls and IO that each user consumed.

I suspect that several users are downloading OSTs or manually importing other data into the online store... causing bandwidth issues, high tx rate (logfiles), and disk IO issues for other users concurrently on the system.

Answer (score 1):

First, Exchange 2010 implemented client throttling policies so that one user can't monopolize the servers. [Technet has a good article describing the default policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297964%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx).

Monitoring of throttling has moved to the Windows Performance Counters. However, since you're specifically asking about RPC Client Access, take note of the last section of the article I linked to; you have to enable RPC Client Access throttling logging manually to get that data.

Comment: Data IS available in counters now, but the benefit of using ExMon is that it also pulls Exchange logs and can show both user names and IP addresses.

(Yes, I'm a bit late to the conversation, but am also looking for similar information.)